# File does not download in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm trying to add functionality for download files on `ASP.NET` website. Below is the class that holds the data:

```
public class L_Attachment
{
    public Int32 ParentId;
    public L_AttachmentTypes Type;
    public String FileName;
    public String FileExtension;
    public Byte[] FileData;

    public enum L_AttachmentTypes
    {
        CONTRACT = 1, 
        RECEIVE = 2
    }
}
```

The `FileData` fields holds the `bytes` to construct the file. Below is my code to download the file.

```
    protected void gvAttachmentList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.CommandName == "DownloadAttachment")
    {
    Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(this.gvAttachmentList.DataKeys[index].Value);

    L_Attachment attachment = L_Attachment.GetById(id);

    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + attachment.FileName + attachment.FileExtension + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", attachment.FileData.Length.ToString());
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.OutputStream.Write(attachment.FileData, 0, attachment.FileData.Length);
        Response.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.Type = MessageType.Error;
        msg.Msg = "Error occurred. Details: " + ex.Message;

        ShowUIMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

But at user end, nothing happens when user press Download button on web page. The file should have to be saved on client PC.

Please help me to find what is wrong in above code.

Comment: You haven't explained how your "Download button" is related to your code that calls `Response.OutputStream.Write`.

Comment: You should change your code to a Redirection to a dedicated handler that will serve the file instead of doing it directly from a Postback event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using update panel then you need to add trigger.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="YourControlID" />
```